# incapsulated if functions in excel formulas not working

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to create a logical function in excel for the following conditions.

if value > 85 then the output should be 2

else if value < 85 the output should be 1

else

value < 65 the output should be 0

The formula I have created has the following syntax:

```
=IF(O25>85;"2";IF(O25<85;"1";IF(O25<65;"0")))
```

But the output for when it's less than 65 fails.
What have I missed here?

Comment: also tried two other solutions:

=IF(O25<65;"0";IF(O25>=65;"1";IF(O25>=85;"2")))
In this case the last condition didn't work out.

Also tired:
=IF(O25<65;"0";IF(O25>=65;"1";"2"))

Comment: If it's <65 it's also <85, so swap the order of those two IF's

Comment: What if the input is exactly 85?  You need some >= or <= to catch the threshold values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an AND statement, or swap order and check if less than 65 first

And statement:`=IF(O25>85;"2";IF(AND(O25<85;O25>=65);"1";IF(O25<65;"0")))`

Change order: `=IF(O25>85;"2";IF(O25<65;"0";IF(O25<85;"1")))`